# email attachments error in django

Tags: python, django

well i am trying to send email with Django this is my views.py

```
def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return TemplateResponse(request, "coming_soon/contact.html", {"contact": "true"})
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        is_valid = form.is_valid()
        errors = [] 
        if is_valid:
            form.save()
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            surname = form.cleaned_data['surname']
            telephone = form.cleaned_data['telephone']
            from_email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            if form.cleaned_data['attachment1']:
                attachment1 = request.FILES['attachment1']
            if form.cleaned_data['attachment2']:
                attachment2 = request.FILES['attachment2']
            if form.cleaned_data['attachment3']:
                attachment3 = request.FILES['attachment3']
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']

            print "data saved"
            #sending email
            to = EMAIL_TO
            sender = EMAIL_HOST_USER
            body = 'name:' + name + ' ' + 'surname:' + surname + ' ' + 'telephone:' + telephone + '\n' + 'message:' + message + '\n' + 'from:' + from_email
            email = EmailMessage(subject, body, sender, [to])
            email.attach_file(attachment1)
            email.attach_file(attachment2)
            email.attach_file(attachment3)
            email.send()
        else:
            for e in form.errors:
                errors.append(e)
        json_errors = json.dumps(errors)
        return HttpResponse("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>window.top.window.upload_finished("+json_errors+");</script>",content_type="text/html")
```

and my models.py:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    attachment1 = ContentTypeRestrictedFileField(upload_to='attachments', blank=True,max_upload_size=settings.FILE_MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE)
    attachment2 = ContentTypeRestrictedFileField(upload_to='attachments', blank=True,max_upload_size=settings.FILE_MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE)
    attachment3 = ContentTypeRestrictedFileField(upload_to='attachments', blank=True,max_upload_size=settings.FILE_MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=4000)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name+" "+self.surname+" "+self.subject
```

and in forms.py i am doing this:

```
class ContactForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
```

adn when i am trying to send email with attachments it says:

```
ERROR Internal Server Error: /en/contact/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\workspace\principal_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 114, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\workspace\principal\apps\coming_soon\views.py", line 87, in contact
    email.attach_file(attachment1)
  File "D:\workspace\principal_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\message.py", line 293, in attach_file
    filename = os.path.basename(path)
  File "D:\workspace\principal_env\lib\ntpath.py", line 198, in basename
    return split(p)[1]
  File "D:\workspace\principal_env\lib\ntpath.py", line 170, in split
    d, p = splitdrive(p)
  File "D:\workspace\principal_env\lib\ntpath.py", line 125, in splitdrive
    if p[1:2] == ':':
TypeError: 'InMemoryUploadedFile' object is not subscriptable
```

please help me fix this problem

Comment: You need to save those files somewhere before sending them through email.

Comment: well i thought i am saving with form.save() @AndreyNelubin

Comment: so you need to use files from saved object, not from `request.FILES`

Answer (score 0):

well it needed path in `email.attach_file()` and i found it with `form.instance.attachment1`
So my email.attach_file() looks like this

```
if form.instance.attachment1:
   email.attach_file(MEDIA_ROOT + '/' + str(form.instance.attachment1))
if form.instance.attachment2:
    email.attach_file(MEDIA_ROOT + '/' + str(form.instance.attachment2))
if form.instance.attachment3:
    email.attach_file(MEDIA_ROOT + '/' + str(form.instance.attachment3))
```

hope it will help someone else